# Multidimensional PHP array search

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I used a php ics parser to extract data from some ics files into an array, which has a basic structure like this:

```
[a] => Array (

   [foo] => Array (

      [0] => 01-02-2018 
      [1] => 02-02-2018
      ...

      )
   [bar] => Array (

      [0] => 19-03-2018
      [1] => 20-03-2018
      ...

      )
   ...
)

[b] => Array (

   [foo] => Array (

      [0] => 31-01-2019
      ...

      )
   [bar] => Array(

      [0] => 14-02-2019
      ...

      )
   ...
)
```

What I want to be able to do is pretty simple:

Input: `19-03-2018`.

Output: `"bar a"`.

I looked up `array_search`, `in_array` and other common solutions but I couldn't wrap my head around how to use them in this particular case.

**Notes:**

- `gettype($Array["a"]["bar"][0])` returns `string`
- Values inside `[foo]` or `[bar]` are unique
- `[foo]` and `[bar]` appear both in `[a]` and `[b]`

Comment: With this array structure it is a `foreach` inside `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have array of arrays of arrays you need to iterate with two `foreach`s:

```
foreach ($Array as $level1_key => $level1_value) {
    foreach ($level1_value as $level2_key => $level2_value) {
        if (in_array('19-03-2018', $level2_value)) {
            echo 'Value found in ' . $level1_key . ' ' . $level2_key;
            // stop both `foreach`s
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```